# If i append the same js script twice, the code gets duplicated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I have a section of a page that can have his html content changed by ajax requests. Also, each content (lets call it "tiny-template") has its own js script that is also appended or detached via js.

Example: user click on button "myBtn1", it loads "tiny-template1" and my js append "myJs1.js".

Then if user click on button "myBtn2", it removes "tiny-template1" and "myJs1.js" and then it loads "tiny-template2" and append "myJs2.js".

I know that the js removed script content stays in the DOM even if we remove the script tag (ex: ) from the html.

So my question is, if user clicks again on button "myBtn1", the script "myJs1.js" will be appended (again). This will result on duplicated js code?

Comment: No, if you remove a `<script>` tag from the document, it will no longer exist in the DOM

Comment: What do you mean by removing the script when `myBtn2` is pressed after `myBtn1`?

Comment: You're wrong, by removing the tag, you do not remove any of its objects, functions etc. from the DOM. So any action started within that tag will prevail, even if you delete the element, that started it in the first place. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Remove the tag from html .. ex: var myScript.destroy() @SaifUrRahman

Comment: Yes & No.. :)  Your previous JS if any code is still referenced, this will stay in memory until all references are lost, and the Garbage collector can do it's job.  So if you say attached something to a Timer / Global etc, you have a memory leak on your hands, if of course you don't handle them.. :)

Comment: @Don-g Of course *handlers* and such the script may have attached will still exist, but the script tag, if removed, will indeed be removed - it's no longer in the DOM, only side-effects it may have initialized will still be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the script *element* exists or not in the DOM probably isn't the issue. The second time you add a script loading `myJs1.js` to the DOM, it will *evaluate* the script a second time, which could cause side effects if the script modifies any global state. Removing a script element does not remove those side-effects. If the scripts don't mutate any sort of global state, you should be ok.